# how to create this type layout in android and that layout show only first time in android Please check image

Tags: android

showing a transparent layout top of the activity only first time[image]

Comment: Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . And this is called ShowCaseView.

Comment: Exact library: https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView

Comment: Check this lib https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt, another one https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView

Answer (score 0):

This is called as **Feature Discovery**. There are different libraries to achieve this.
Try [this link](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView)

To show this only for the first time you can use `Shared Preference` flag, make it true inside `onClickListener` of your *Target View* .